# malloc works, cudaHostAlloc segfaults?

Tags: c, cuda

I am new to CUDA and I want to use `cudaHostAlloc`. I was able to isolate my problem to this following code. Using `malloc` for host allocation works, using `cudaHostAlloc` results in a segfault, possibly because the area allocated is invalid? When I dump the pointer in both cases it is not null, so `cudaHostAlloc` returns something...

works

```
    in_h = (int*) malloc(length*sizeof(int)); //works
    for (int i = 0;i<length;i++)
            in_h[i]=2;
```

doesn't work

```
    cudaHostAlloc((void**)&in_h,length*sizeof(int),cudaHostAllocDefault); 
    for (int i = 0;i<length;i++)
            in_h[i]=2; //segfaults
```

---

**Standalone Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
void checkDevice()
{
        cudaDeviceProp info;
        int deviceName;
        cudaGetDevice(&deviceName);
        cudaGetDeviceProperties(&info,deviceName);
        if (!info.deviceOverlap)
        {
                printf("Compute device can't use streams and should be discarded.");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
}
int main()
{
        checkDevice();
        int *in_h;
        const int length = 10000;
        cudaHostAlloc((void**)&in_h,length*sizeof(int),cudaHostAllocDefault);
        printf("segfault comming %d\n",in_h);
        for (int i = 0;i<length;i++)
        {
                in_h[i]=2; // Segfaults here
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

~
**Invocation**

```
[id129]$ nvcc fun.cu 
[id129]$ ./a.out 
segfault comming 327641824
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**Details**

Program is run in interactive mode on a cluster. I was told that an invocation of the program from the compute node pushes it to the cluster. Have not had any trouble with other home made toy cuda codes.

**Edit**

```
cudaError_t err = cudaHostAlloc((void**)&in_h,length*sizeof(int),cudaHostAllocDefault);
printf("Error status is %s\n",cudaGetErrorString(err));
```

gives driver error...

```
Error status is CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
```

Comment: I just built and tested a sample with your code (commenting out the malloc line and un-commenting the cudaHostAlloc line).  It does not segfault for me.  I used `int length = 1000;` and `int *in_h;`   Perhaps you should create a small reproducer that is a complete compilable application, paste it into your question, and then provide the command line you used to compile it along with system details like operating system, CUDA version, and GPU type.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks I posted the code. I don't know the GPU type but I think I tested it for this kind of functionality...

Comment: See if cudaHostAlloc (and other cuda functions) is returning any error. If it fails, no memory has been allocated and the segfaults seems likely.

Comment: @Pavan I feel silly that I didn't try that. I get the following error `Error status is CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version` . So I'm going to contact the cluster administrators. Post your suggestion as an answer so that I can give you credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always check for Errors. It is likely that `cudaHostAlloc` is failing to allocate any memory. If it fails, you are not bailing but are rather writing to unallocated address space. When using `malloc` it allocates memory as requested and does not fail. But there are cases when malloc may result in failures as well, so it is best to do checks on the pointer before writing into it.

For future, it may be best to do something like this

```
int *ptr = NULL;
// Allocate using cudaHostAlloc or malloc
// If using cudaHostAlloc check for success 
if (!ptr) ERROR_OUT();
// Write to this memory
```

**EDIT** (Response to edit in the question)

The error message indicates you have an older driver compared to the toolkit. If you do not want to be stuck for a while, try to download an older version of cuda toolkit that is compatible with your driver. You can install it in your user account and use its nvcc + libraries for temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

Your segfault is not caused by the writes to the block of memory allocated by cudaHostAlloc, but rather from trying to 'free' an address returned from cudaHostAlloc. I was able to reproduce your problem using the code you provided, but replacing free with cudaFreeHost fixed the segfault for me.

[cudaFreeHost](http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp422/resources/cuda/html/group__CUDART__MEMORY_gedaeb2708ad3f74d5b417ee1874ec84a.html#gedaeb2708ad3f74d5b417ee1874ec84a)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it actually segfaults earlier :-) . I am going to edit my post to reflect this change.

Comment: Have you used gdb to locate the specific point of failure? Information on exactly which iteration of the loop segfaults (for instance) might be useful. When I tested the code on my card, it ran fine once I replaced free so if it isn't that then it might not be easily reproducable.